# How to get the role of a QPushButton created by a QDialogButtonBox?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, widget

I'm trying get all the button child widgets of a currently active window. The buttons were created through **QDialogButtonBox**. I'm trying to get the roles of each button so I can identify which button is the OK, CANCEL, or SAVE button. However I'm getting an error with the following code:

```
QWidget *pWin = QApplication::activeWindow();
QList<QPushButton *> allPButtons = pWin->findChildren<QPushButton *>();
QListIterator<QPushButton*> i(allPButtons);
while( i.hasNext() )
{
    QDialogButtonBox *pButtonRole = new QDialogButtonBox();
    QDialogButtonBox::ButtonRole role = pButtonRole->buttonRole(i.next()); 
    qDebug() << "buttonRole: " << role << endl ;  
    //the value of role here is -1, which means it's an invalid role...      
}
```

I'm getting a negative value when getting the button's role :(

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Either do how jkerian said, or if you use standard buttons and simply need one of the buttons: QPushButton* ok = buttonBox->button( QDialogButtonBox::Ok )

Comment: I tried QDialogButtonBox pButtonRole = new QDialogButtonBox(); QDialogButtonBox::ButtonRole role = pButtonRole->buttonRole(i.next()); qDebug() << "buttonRole: " << role << endl ; but I'm getting an invalid role... -1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new empty `QDialogButtonBox` which has no idea about `buttons` in `allPButtons` list. Calling `buttonRole()` on them returns -1 (InvalidRole) because `buttons` are not in that `button-box`.

You must do as jkerian wrote and `myButtonBoxPtr` must point to the `QDialogButtonBox` which is already in your window.

You can try something like this (if you have one ButtonBox):

```
QDialogButtonBox *box = pWin->findChild<QDialogButtonBox *>();
foreach(QAbstractButton* button, box->buttons())
{ qDebug() << box->buttonRole(button); }
```

Comment: I see. However, I can't figure how to get the instance of the QDialogButtonBox. What I have is a list of all the buttons in a window. How do I get the instance of myButtonBoxPtr?

Comment: You can get list of QDialogButtonBoxes in the same way you got QPushButtons list.

Answer (score 3):

You can't call a non-static method like that. You need to have the `QDialogButtonBox` variable and call that particular instance for `buttonRole()` to work.

```
QDialogButtonBox::ButtonRole role = myButtonBoxPtr->buttonRole(i.next());
```

Comment: I tried QDialogButtonBox pButtonRole = new QDialogButtonBox();
            QDialogButtonBox::ButtonRole role = pButtonRole->buttonRole(i.next());

               qDebug() << "buttonRole: " << role << endl ; but I'm getting an invalid role... -1...